# “output” — 2019/5/31 — 16:24 — page 1 — #1 appears on the very top of my paper

Tags: header-footer

how do I remove “output” — 2019/5/31 — 16:24 — page 1 — #1? I'm using a template so I'm searching for the code that causes this. I'm using the following template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/dtu-poster/nfchvswyhcnq)

Comment: I would recommend working through the ideas in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497 in order to narrow down what's causing this to happen.

Comment: That's created by the `crop` package.

Comment: thank you egreg that was exactly the problem.